# Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

My gradle has stopped working all of sudden. Current configuration is that:

- Environment variable as GRADLE_HOME, pointing to Gradle-3.2.1

Simply ran the command **gradle** in command prompt, and I get following message:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
```

Running with debug gives the following additional message:

```
23:11:45.439 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Initialized native services in: C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\native
23:11:45.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files is not available.  Continuing with fallback.
23:11:45.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemServices] Using JDK 7 file service org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.jdk7.WindowsJdk7Symlink
23:11:45.924 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Executing build 3b214279-3ced-4a5f-ab1e-457e044f7c3f.1 in daemon client {pid=924}
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Software Loopback Interface 1
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Software Loopback Interface 1
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /10.172.37.80
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
23:11:45.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:11:45.955 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
23:11:45.955 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
23:11:45.955 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
23:11:45.955 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
23:11:46.002 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
23:11:46.017 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Attempting to connect to [b4241497-ed70-4c43-8b4f-854517103401 port:53311, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]].
23:11:46.017 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Trying to connect to address /127.0.0.1.
23:11:46.017 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Connected to address /127.0.0.1:53311.
23:11:46.080 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=7592, address=[b4241497-ed70-4c43-8b4f-854517103401 port:53311, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1536894331315, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=7ee1af1d-8759-44bf-84d3-69e6dd38a351,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\daemon,pid=7592,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xms1g,-Xmx4g,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request Build{id=3b214279-3ced-4a5f-ab1e-457e044f7c3f.1, currentDir=D:\<myProject>}.
23:11:46.080 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
23:11:46.111 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@198d6542 from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=7592, address=[b4241497-ed70-4c43-8b4f-854517103401 port:53311, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1536894331315, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=7ee1af1d-8759-44bf-84d3-69e6dd38a351,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\daemon,pid=7592,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xms1g,-Xmx4g,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be starting).
23:11:46.111 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 7592). The daemon log file: C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\daemon\3.2.1\daemon-7592.out.log
23:11:46.111 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth] Starting 5th build in daemon [uptime: 11 mins 37.485 secs, performance: 100%, no major garbage collections]
23:11:46.111 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
23:11:46.111 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=7ee1af1d-8759-44bf-84d3-69e6dd38a351,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\daemon,pid=7592,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xms1g,-Xmx4g,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
23:11:46.111 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
23:11:46.174 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@f173c7e
23:11:46.189 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 14: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
23:11:46.189 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=7592, address=[b4241497-ed70-4c43-8b4f-854517103401 port:53311, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1536894331315, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=7ee1af1d-8759-44bf-84d3-69e6dd38a351,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\daemon,pid=7592,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xms1g,-Xmx4g,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
23:11:46.189 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
23:11:46.205 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
23:11:46.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

Also ran, full strack trace and received the following:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.gradle.plugin.repository.internal.DefaultPluginRepositoryFactory.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry$BuildScopeServices.createPluginRepositoryFactory(PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:462)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:796)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.addGetter(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:426)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.addGetter(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:421)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.mixInDynamicAware(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:206)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:105)
```

Tried to search around those two exceptions, but to no avail as of yet. Any suggestion or ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Setting gradle version from 4.7 to 4.8 fixed this issue for me. In gradle-wrapper.properties, use this line instead of old one:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

I probably broke *gradle 4.7* by installing Java JDK 11. The solution was to upgrade *gradle*.

As I'm using MacOS and as I have installed *gradle* using *homebrew*, I've upgraded it like so:

```
brew upgrade gradle
```

Now I have *gradle 5.0* and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 4.7 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file is working for me.

I did have to proceed afterwards with a File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart, and a Build / Clean Project afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `distributionUrl` in `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` had a typo. I am using like following.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: If you have this error specifically (Which is similar to the main one):]

You can try these solutions:
If you want to do it the easy way:

Windows Defender>Virus & Threat protection>Ransomware Protection> Unable the protection.

Windows Defender>Virus & Threat protection>Virus & Threat protection settings (Manage settings)>Real-time protection> Unable real-time protection.

If you want to do it the best way (considering your security):

Windows Defender>Virus & Threat protection>Ransomware Protection> APP through monitored folder access> Add allowed APP> last blocked app> Add the Studio64/Studio.exe (You need to enable hidden folders in order to open ProgramData).

Then, go to your Windows Explorer `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History` Delete everything in that folder.

Check if your project's folder is in the exclusions folder. Windows Defender> Virus & Threat protection> Virus & threat protection settings> Add or remove exclusions.

Android Studio should work fine now :D.