# Gradle build could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory

Tags: java, gradle, export

Im exporting this gradle project im working on by using `./gradlew build` but it gives me an error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Does anyone know the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324546/could-not-create-service-of-type-scriptpluginfactory)